# Using bearer tokens in ASP.NET Core with basic configuration

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi, bearer-token

I'm migrating an ASP.NET MVC 5 project to ASP.NET Core 5 MVC. The first project uses tokens to Web API authorization and it is configured very simple in Startup.Auth.cs file:

```
public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
{
    ...

    // Enable the application to use bearer tokens to authenticate users
    app.UseOAuthBearerTokens(new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions
    {
        TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/Token"),
        Provider = new ApplicationOAuthProvider(PublicClientId, UserManagerFactory),
        AuthorizeEndpointPath = new PathString("/api/Account/ExternalLogin"),
        AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(14),
        AllowInsecureHttp = true
    });
}
```

Now I'm lost how should I configure bearer tokens in ASP.NET Core 5. All examples I found are very complex or don't work (or there are incompleted). I don't know if I should use JWT or other one.

Is there any easy solution?

Comment: It seems that you are using external login, if that is the case, can you tell us which external provider you are using?Here is an article about [external login](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/social/?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio) you could check it. Besides, you could also check the following article: [JWT Authentication](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/jwt-json-web-token-authentication-in-asp-net-core/) and [Bearer Token](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/bearer-token-authentication-in-asp-net-core/), then use them in your application.

Comment: I'm not using external login, maybe ```AuthorizeEndpointPath = new PathString("/api/Account/ExternalLogin")``` line is not necessary. I will check these articles, but it seems that ASP.NET Core is more complicated than old ASP.NET...